# SSL WITH IIS 10

Tags: windows, ssl, iis, server, ssl-certificate

I set up a site on IIS 10 by installing the certificate, I am facing this problem, this is my binding in IIS

1. [www.namesite.it](http://www.namesite.it): 80
2. [www.namesite.it](http://www.namesite.it): 443
3. namesite.it: 80
4. namesite.it: 443

this is the scenario:

https://www.namesite.it -----> IT WORKS

https://www.namesite.it/pricing.aspx ----> IT WORKS

https://namesite.it/ -------------------> IT WORKS

https://namesite.it/pricing.aspx ---> Error "The connection is not private" NET:: ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Did I do something wrong with IIS?

Thank you

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#background You forgot to configure SNI for both HTTPS bindings.

Comment: This is certificate error and it is due to misconfiguration of the SSL. make sure certificate issue to your domain and name is correct and make sure it is from trusted authority.
In case it is local project, you may add the server certificate to the trusted list.